# ZMQ SNDMORE and NOBLOCK interact differently depending on whether the socket is connected or bound

Tags: c#, zeromq

I am using the C# bindings for zmq, and I notice a different behaviour for sndmore and noblock depending on whether the socket is connected or bound.

If there is no client connected to the endpoint, the following scenario blocks on the first send:

```
        Context zmqContext = new Context(1);
        Socket zmqSocket = zmqContext.Socket(<any socket type>);

        zmqSocket.Bind("tcp://*:5555");

        zmqSocket.Send("hello", Encoding.UTF8, SendRecvOpt.SNDMORE);
        zmqSocket.Send("world", Encoding.UTF8, SendRecvOpt.SNDMORE);
        zmqSocket.Send("ok, I'm done!", Encoding.UTF8, SendRecvOpt.NOBLOCK);
```

While this one does not block at all if there is nothing at the endpoint:

```
        Context zmqContext = new Context(1);
        Socket zmqSocket = zmqContext.Socket(<any socket type>);

        zmqSocket.Connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

        zmqSocket.Send("hello", Encoding.UTF8, SendRecvOpt.SNDMORE);
        zmqSocket.Send("world", Encoding.UTF8, SendRecvOpt.SNDMORE);
        zmqSocket.Send("ok, I'm done!", Encoding.UTF8, SendRecvOpt.NOBLOCK);
```

It seems a little strange that I must use the noblock flag on all sends in one scenario, but only on the last send in the other scenario. I can't find anything in the zmq documentation relating to this. Can anyone tell me if this is intentional behavior for zmq, or is it an idiosyncrasy of the c# bindings? Is there any documentation on this that I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bug; definitely not documented behaviour. Can you send a test case to the zeromq-dev list? It would be best to make one in C, so that we can exclude the C# bindings.

Comment: Ok, we have upgraded zmq version a few times since I posted this issue. I will go and check if it is still a problem before I open any issues. :)